# jQuery colorbox and iframe don't overlay each other on first attempt

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, colorbox

I have a parent application that uses jQuery 3.3.1 & jQuery-UI 1.12 that must call another child application that uses jQuery 1.4.2 and colorbox.js. The parent application will use a jQuery-UI dialog window to load the outdated jQuery 1.4.2 JSP page. This loads the JSP fine into the modal window, however, clicking on the buttons in the JSP, a colorbox iframe window should appear but I see 2 windows - a blank colorbox on top followed by the loaded iframe below it vertically.

What is odd is this only happens the first time the code is loaded, subsequent closing of the modal window and reloading it will show the iframe on top of the colorbox. So somewhere it must cache it, but why it is not loading on the first execution I cannot understand.

The parent application previously used deprecated IE modal dialogs. This was not an issue before since IE creates these dialogs in separate HTML windows. Now I'm using jQuery and the code is inline to the same page.

Tried upgrading the child code to jQuery 3.3.1 and it was a disaster. jQuery code had call stack errors unrelated to my code so I stuck with 1.4.2 jQuery. I tried 'return false;' in the onClick events in the JSP page. I added jQuery 1.4.2 with noConflict(true) (what you see in the latest posted code) to the parent application in case there were any jQuery conflicts (the base JSP page), but the same issue occurs.

```
The called child JSP declaration -

<script src="/jsp/QualManager/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jsp/QualManager/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsp/QualManager/css/colorbox.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsp/QualManager/css/QM_CB.css">
        <script src="/jsp/QualManager/js/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jsp/QualManager/js/tip.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsp/QualManager/css/QM.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsp/QualManager/css/buttons.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jsp/QualManager/css/tooltips.css">

The parent application code declaration -

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jsp/databaseManager/css/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jsp/databaseManager/css/jquery-ui.structure-1.12.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/jsp/databaseManager/css/jquery-ui.theme-1.12.1.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $old142jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/ChangeDetection.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/Utilities.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/ValidateGeo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/ValidateRequired.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/FAUCheck.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/Register.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/FieldValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/databaseManager/js/Option.js"></script>

.... The parent application code using jQuery UI modal window -

var jQueryOriginal = jQuery;

    if(window.jQuery)
    {
        console.log('Original jQuery: ', jQuery.fn.jquery);
    }

    $("body").append("<div id='modalViewCredentialsWindow'></div>");
    var dialogWindow = $("#modalViewCredentialsWindow").dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: true, draggable: true, 
        resizable: true, //dialogClass: "no-close", 
        height: 650, width: 1100, 
        modal: true, title: "View Credentials",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        open: function(event, ui)
        {
            var element = $old142jQuery("<span id='innerCredentialsHTML'></span>")
            element.load(url, 
            function(response, status, xhr)
            {
                $old142jQuery("#modalViewCredentialsWindow").html(element);
            });
            //$old142jQuery("#innerCredentialsHTML").remove();
        },
        close: function(event, ui)
        {
            window.jQuery = window.$ = jQueryOriginal;
            dialogWindow.dialog("destroy").remove();
            console.log('jQuery version: ', jQuery.fn.jquery);
        }
    });

The called colorbox on click in the called JSP page - 

function openSmallCB(url)
            {
                $.fn.colorbox(
                { 
                    width: "100%", height: "100%",
                    iframe: true, 
                    maxWidth: 460, maxHeight: 425,
                    transition: "fade", 
                    rel: "nofollow", 
                    resize: "true", 
                    href: "/jsp/QualManager/" + url, 
                    opacity: 0, overlayClose: false, opacity: 0.85, close: "", 
                    onClosed: function()
                    { 
                        $('#cboxClose', parent.document).unbind();
                        $('#cboxClose', parent.document).bind('click', 
                        function()
                        {
                            parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
                        });
                    } 
                });
                return false;
            }
```

I would like to see the expected output to be the same no matter how many times I open it, but I am getting two windows (colorbox & iframe) when loading the first time. I get the problem regardless if I introduce jQuery 1.4.2 to the parent application or not. I will return jQuery to 3.3.1 on close of the modal window so that it can be opened again (it loses jQuery-UI without resetting it again)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uIxw.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed to declare the colorbox.js in the newer parent code, that's why it never loaded right on the first try.